# Necromancer Life Tap

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, house-rules, homebrew, balance

One of my players wants to play a necromancer, using the following homebrew class:  https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Necromancer_(5e_Class)

I have some concerns about the feature "Life Tap". From my understanding, this feature causes all of your melee touch spells to heal you for the damage they deal, and you gain a spell that can overheal you and give you temporary hit points.

It seems that, while the spell can only be used once after a long rest, the leech effect from melee touch spells is indefinite, so if you are using a cantrip melee touch spell such as Shocking Grasp you will be able to keep healing up with it for as long as you have enemies you can hit in melee range.

- Is this reading of the feature correct?  Does the feature allow unlimited healing via damaging touch spells?
- If so, is this a balance concern?  It seems that it would remove the need for any other healing spells or resting at all, which would spoil some of the fun in the adventure.
- I'm considering completely removing the leech on melee touch spells this feature gives in my games, and instead keeping only the 1/rest ability it gives. Would that be a reasonable houserule?  Any other advice for balancing this?

Comment: If you're new to D&D, it's probably not a good idea to be using a homebrewed class that you don't have any playtesting data for.

Comment: Why use a homebrew class instead of the Wizard School of Necromancy that's included in the PHB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It does not apply to all spells.

It looks like the part that is confusing you is the portion I have marked in bold below.

> Starting at 1st level, **your melee touch spells drain the life from your enemies and heal you**. As an action, you can make a melee spell attack to drain 1d6 + your Charisma modifier of hit points from any creatures, making you regain hit points equal to the amount drained. If you drain more hit points than the maximum amount of hit points you have, you gain temporary hit points equal to the amount of healing provided over your maximum hit points. Also, if this feature kills the creature, you instead double the temporary hit points gained from using this feature. This feature's damage increases by 1d6 when you reach 5th level (2d6), 11th level (3d6), and 17th level (4d6). You regain use of this feature after you finish a long rest.

This appears to be flavor text (poorly written and in need of revision, since "melee touch spell" is not a term in D&D 5e) that describes the feature whose rules follow that in the rest of the paragraph. The rules go on to describe a *specific* melee spell attack (the so-called Life Tap) that can be used as an action and how you can use it to drain life.

The feature does not appear to be intended to apply to *all* spells that involve melee spell attacks, since nothing in the paragraph actually explains how that would work. Rather, it explains a specific new action you can use and how its mechanics work.

## My advice to you.

The website D&D Wiki has no affiliation with Wizards of the Coast, the company that produces D&D, and any content listed as "homebrew" on that site is unofficial and created by somebody in the community, possibly without any peer review or playtesting. If you are new to D&D, I caution you against letting one of your players use a class like this. It is a recipe for disaster. Stick with the official content in the *Player's Handbook* and other official Wizards books until you yourself are confident enough to ascertain whether a feature is balanced.

Note that there *is* already a necromancer option in the *Player's Handbook*. It's the necromancy school for the wizard. It has a feature which can absorb life from enemies killed by the wizard's spells. Since it was designed and playtested by Wizards of the Coast (the producers of D&D 5e), you can safely assume that it is balanced and ready for use at the table.

Comment: Thank you very much, that clears things up perfectly for me.
My player wants to play only necromancer, i dont think i can talk him out of it, but now i have no issues with the class so i believe it will be fine.

Comment: Note that there is a necromancer in the PHB, as the necromancy specialization for the Wizard. It has a feature which can absorb life from enemies, and it has been playtested by the designers of D&D and can be presumed to be balanced.

Comment: I actually did not realize that and i feel stupid for it, ill see what i can do.